# Undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category despite linking with boost_system

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-system

My compilation command is:

> `g++ -I/home/foo/boost_1_56_0 -L/home/foo/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lboost_thread main.cpp foo.cpp`

I get an undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category` error despite the fact that I link it with `-lboost_thread`.

I also get undefined references to:

`boost::system::generic_category` and `pthread_detach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should   specify the libraries ***after*** the source file(s).

Also, prefer `-pthread` over manually linking libpthread.so

> `g++ -I/home/foo/boost_1_56_0 -L/home/foo/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib -pthread main.cpp foo.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread`