# Cannot compile with boost?

Tags: c++, boost

Attempting to create a simple WebSocket c++ application, the library I am using relies on boost.
I have attempted to add boost to my project but it refuses to compile, heres my cpp file

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/client.hpp>

#include <websocketpp/common/thread.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/common/memory.hpp>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am attemting to compile it with `g++ -I. -Iboost_1_58_0 /home/cabox/workspace/main.cpp -o /home/cabox/workspace/bin/exe`, but all i get is

```
In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int,int)':                                                            
main.cpp:(.text+0xfba): undefined reference to`boost::system::generic_category()'
```

My folder layout is just my Main.cpp file, the boost_1_58_0 & the websocketpp folders all being in the same parent directory, what is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to give `main` a return type, by the way. Though it's compiling just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
-lboost_system
```

(see also [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix))

Optionally specify the library directory with `-L`

Make sure it's after the cpps

[Undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category despite linking with boost_system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317955/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category-despite-linking-with-boos)

Comment: When i add this, it says it cannont find boost_system.

Comment: "_Optionally specify the library directory with -L_" (see also the two linked answers in case you need more background explanation)

Comment: Read [some documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/index.html). After you build, it's usually `-/boost_1_58_0/stage/lib/` (default build settings).

Comment: I have tried following the linked documentation but that didnt work either, also i dont have /stage/lib in my boost directory.. I'll attempt to redownload see if that's the problem.

Comment: That is not the problem. Did you build? There's bound to be FAQs on building boost on your system. Otherwise, ask a focused question about it. Be sure to specify exactly what you tried and where you are stuck.